# Why do I get error when I use to: instead of :to => in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running 
ruby 1.9.3p194
rails 3.2.8 
Gems for test:
guard (1.3.2)
guard-rspec (1.2.1, 0.5.5)
guard-spork (1.2.0, 0.3.2)

In the Hash assignment I get error (Error in the test run). for example

```
# This passes fine
page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'TEST') 

#this dump an error
page.should have_selector('h1', text:'TEST')
```

The syntax error is this: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kDO_BLOCK (SyntaxError)
Isnt the test: has the same effect at :test =>

Thank you for your help in advance.

To run the test I use this command:
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/test_page_spec.rb

This is where it fails.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running Ruby 1.8. `{ text: 'TEST' }` is a new hash syntax in Ruby 1.9.

Try to check the version by writing `puts RUBY_VERSION` in that file.

Comment: No just test it Ruby 1.9.3. As I said my error is not in the ruby it is when I run the test. using those gems that I mentioned.

Comment: Your gems are using ruby 1.8 then. Try to run the test with `puts RUBY_VERSION` in it.

Comment: Ok I actually see in the error it uses: Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ So how do I change it? I am using rvm and it is running ruby 1.9.3. What should I do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: I just ran echo $GEM_HOME in the application folder and this came up: /Users/mrh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of solved.

For now I will be using the spork server then run the test from terminal. I have updated the Gem and it fixes some of the issues and brought more :(

Anyway thanks for your help.